# UITableView: Update label in custom cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have two Table Views in one View Controller. One of the Table Views is using a custom cell. I have made a custom class for the two Table Views.

In the custom cell, I have some labels and two buttons. The buttons is a pluss button, and a minus button. I want these buttons to add 1, or subtract 1 from the label called counterLabel.

Custom Class:

```
import UIKit  
class MainTableViewCell : UITableViewCell  
{  
    @IBOutlet weak var refMainCell: UILabel!  

}  

class SubTableViewCell : UITableViewCell  
{  
    var counter: Int = 0  
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!  
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!  
    @IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: UIButton)  
    {  
        counter -= 1  
    }  
    @IBAction func plussButton(_ sender: UIButton)  
    {  
        counter += 1  

    }  
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!  
}
```

Setup from Main View Controller:

```
import UIKit  
class MenyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {  



    struct Objects {  
        var sectionName: String!  
        var SectionObjects: [String]!  
        var subtitleArray: [String]!  
    }  

    var hovedMenyArray = ["Main1", "Main2", "Main3", "Main4"]  
    var underMenyArray = [Objects]()  
    var subtitleArray = ["", "","",""] /  
    let detailArray = ["Detail1", "Detail2", "Detail3", "Detail4", "Detail5", "Detail6", "Detail7", "Detail8"]  

    @IBOutlet weak var hovedMenyTableView: UITableView!  
    @IBOutlet weak var underMenyTableView: UITableView!  

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  

        underMenyArray = [Objects.init(sectionName: "Section 1", SectionObjects: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"], subtitleArray: ["Subtitle 1", "Subtitle 2", ""]),  
                          Objects.init(sectionName: "Section 2", SectionObjects: ["Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"], subtitleArray: ["Subtitle 4", "Subtitle 5", "Subtitle 6"]),  
                          Objects.init(sectionName: "Section 3", SectionObjects: ["Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8"], subtitleArray: ["Subtitle 7", "Subtitle 8", "Subtitle 9"]),  
                          Objects.init(sectionName: "Section 4", SectionObjects: ["Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8"], subtitleArray: ["Subtitle 10", "Subtitle 11", "Subtitle 12"])]  
       }
```

And:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  
        {  
           if (tableView == MainTableView)  
            {  
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell  
                cell.refMainCell.text = mainArray[indexPath.row]  
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = subtitleArray[indexPath.row]  
                cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator  
                return cell  
            }else  
            {  
                let cell: UITableViewCell  
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubCell", for: indexPath)  
                if let customCell = cell as? SubTableViewCell  
                {  
                    customCell.label.text = subArray[indexPath.section].SectionObjects[indexPath.row]  
                    customCell.SubtitleLabel.text = subArray[indexPath.section].subtitleArray[indexPath.row]  
                    customCell.counterLabel.text = String (customCell.counter)  //Here I'm trying to use the pluss and minus buttons.

                return cell  
            }  
       }
```

In this setup, the counterLabel sort of works, but it updates labels in every section. I suppose that's right, since its not told to update a specific cell.
How should I go about to get the right label to update?

I also have to scroll down and up for the label to update, but I suppose there is a update function to use as well?

Comment: you would at least update the counterLabel.text in the plussButton method.

Answer (score 1):

Add an observer to your counter variable. The correct label will update every time the value of counter changes.

```
var counter: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        counterLabel.text = String(counter)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This takes care of the label update. But it seems the labels is randomly incremented. If I press the plussButton in the first cell, the right label updates, but when I scroll down in the table, every other label is updated as well. And when I scroll back up, the label in the second cell is incremented with one, but not the first cell.  Could this have anything to do with `customCell.counterLabel.text = String (customCell.counter)` ?

Comment: The table view is reusing cells that are not visible anymore when you scroll. You will have to store the counter value in your data source to keep track of the values.